# Redrawing a UIView using NSTimer not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nstimer, drawrect

I subclassed UIView in order to draw a line that changes position every second. I am using NSTimer to call setNeedsDisplay in order to update the view but the results are not correct. It is drawing old and new lines. Here is my LineView.h/m code:

LineView.h:

```
@interface LineView : UIView
@property(nonatomic, assign) int length;
@end
```

LineView.m:

```
#import "LineView.h"
@implementation LineView
- (void)setLength:(int)length {
    _length = length;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
    UIBezierPath *line = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
    [line addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100+_length)];
    line.lineWidth = 10;
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [line stroke];
}
@end
```

In my ViewController.m file, in viewDidLoad, I init lineView and start the timer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _length = 100;

    _lineView = [[LineView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _lineView.length = _length;
    [self.view addSubview:_lineView];

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer*)timer {
    _length += 20;
    self.lineView.length = _length;
}
```

I want to do this all programmatically and not use storyboards or xibs. If I subclass the view in storyboard and create an outlet to it, then the view is updated correctly but I want to avoid touching the storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy that won't do anything. [According to the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:), "*The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing code there.*"

Comment: @originaluser2 Yeah. I just reviewed some of my code and none of my `drawRect:` methods call `[super drawRect:]`. Never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_lineView.opaque = NO;
_lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

try this. I have run your project with this it doing good.

Comment: you can set you background cold to any i set it to black.

Comment: please also saw the documentation for opaque and clearContextBeforeDrawing property of uiview.